# Отличие & от && в определённом случае

Tags: php

Такое условие:

```
<?php
    $age = '20';

    if ($age>=15 && $age<=19) {
        echo "ОК";
    }
?>
```

Почему в случае `&&` и если поменять на `&`, то ничего не выведет? Чем тогда отличаются эти операторы?

Но если

Comment: `&&` - логический оператор, `&` - побитовый

Comment: И `$age>=15 && $age<=19` и `$age>=15 & $age<=19` в вашем примере вернут **один и тот же результат** (разница лишь в типе значения). Пруф: http://ideone.com/crHmAj А вопрос ни о чем!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

&& - это логическое "И"

Работает оно так: C = A && B

```
╭────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────╮
│     A      │     B       │     C       │
╞════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ true       │ true        │  true       │
│ true       │ false       │  false      │
│ false      │ true        │  false      │  
│ false      │ false       │  false      │     
└────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

& - это побитовое "И". Работает оно так:

C = A & B

1. A и B раскладываются в битовое представление. Допустим A=12, а B=23, тогда (считаем их за байты)

   ```
   A=00001100
   B=00010111
   ```
2. После этого к каждой паре соответствующих бит данных A и B применяется логическое "И" (см. таблицу выше)

   ```
   A = 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
   B = 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
   C = 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 = 3
   ```

Следовательно, 12 & 23 = 3

Теперь, что касается вашего случая. PHP - это язык с динамической типизацией, отсюда вся "магия".

`$age>=15 && $age<=19` - тут все понятно, надеюсь? Возвращает true если $age находится между 15 и 19.

`$age>=15 & $age<=19`. Что же происходит тут? Все просто, сначала выполняются два сравнения, так как у `>=` и `<=` приоритет выше, эти сравнения возвращают логические значения: true и false. Потом наступает очередь оператора `&`, но он не работает с логическим типом, поэтому сначала происходит конвертация `true=>1` и `false=>0`, к этим значениям применяется побитовое `И` и результат преобразуется обратно в логическое значение, 0 в false и 1 в true.